# need videos on separate page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>World Map</title>
    <body>
<p>Click on a clickable area of the map for more info.</p>
<img src ="worldmap.gif" width="576" height="307" alt="World Map" usemap="#worldmap">

<map name="worldmap">

<area shape="rect" coords="265,49,279,64" href="ukanthem.mp4" alt="anthem" onclick="playVideo()"> 
<video id="video1" class="true" autoplay controls width="420">
<source src="ukanthem.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="ukanthem.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<video id="video2" class=flase" width="420" controls>
<source src="beef.mp4">
</video>
<button id="hideButton" onclick="swap();">Switch</button>


<script>
var flag=true;
function swap() {
var myVideo1=document.getElementById("Video1");
var myVideo2=document.getElementById("video2");
flag=!flag;
video1.setAttribute("class", flag);
video2.setAttribute("class", !flag);
if (flag) {
    video2.pause();
    video1.play();
} else {
    video1.pause();
    video2.play();
}
}
</script>


</map>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

I'm creating an interactive gif image where upon click of certain areas, it takes you to a page that plays a video, which you can then switch to another video, my videos appear on the same page as the interactive map. I would like them on a separate page which is accessed upon click of the coordinated area

Answer (score 0):

I would change the href to a different page instead of the mp4 file and add the mp4 you want to play as a parameter. Let the other page read the parameter and display the video.

For instance:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="265,49,279,64" href="playVideo.php?video=ukanthem.mp4" alt="anthem" target="_blank">
```

You could instead of a php file use a plain html file and let javascript read the parameter from the URL.